# How to get page load time for a single page application(SPA) using backbone,jquery, require js?

Tags: javascript, cordova, backbone.js, requirejs, single-page-application

I am building a mobile application using backbone, jquery and require js. I am trying to get the time difference between page init and onShow and but it is not giving proper load time as I am doing lazy loading using require js, and the number of lazy loading in each onShow is dynamic. Can anyone help to figure out a way to calculate how much time the page took to load upon all the elements getting loaded in the DOM including the lazy loading and any other event binding if I am doing in setTimeout, for example.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: page load time extension for chrome does an ok job. If you search for "page load time" by Alexander Vykhodtsev you should find it.

Comment: @Icewine I need to get load time dynamically as and when the page loads and log it. It is a hybrid mobile application running on ios and android. I am aware of the Performance tab in chrome, but I don't think that can help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `console.time('Timer1')` at the start, then when the code you want to time is finished executing call `console.timeEnd('Timer1')` and that will console-out the timer value as accurate as it can be.

Comment: So say you have multiple require js page loading in an onShow() event, we need to go inside each and put a console.log ? I think this is not a proper way, and will only increase complexity as number of page loading required increases. Also, the page binding done using require js is async, so putting start and end time in console.log will be a confusing thing.

Comment: Are you really using requirejs in an async way? if you're defining your modules like this `define(['dep1', 'dep2', function(dep1, dep2) {...})` or like this `define(function(require) { var dep1 = require('bla/dep'); ... })` then you are telling require to load all dependencies before your code is run.

Comment: Now if you're really using async require like this `require(['dep'], function() { // success callback })` then you need to carefully monitor your callbacks or use promises to track their resolve.